# h:commandLink behaviour in jsf 1.2

Tags: jsf-1.2

I have 2 commandLink in my page. A user has to fill in the details in the input text box (I have used h:inputText for this and all fields are mandatory), and click on "Submit". If a user dont wish to fill in any of these fields there is a link provided below Submit for "Skipping this activitiy" . This skip link will redirect to some other page. Both Submit link and Skip link are h:commandLink. I cant use h:outputLink for Skip because when user clicks on Skip I want to call bean and do some business checks.

Now, when a user doesn't fill in any of the details in the fields, but instead clicks on Skip link, the required=true attribute of h:inputText is getting fired. I want this to get fired only when user clicks on Submit without filling in any details and not when he clicks on Skip link.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `immediate="true"` to the commandLink.

It will make sure that all the input fields where `immediate="true"` hasn't been defined will be skipped in processing and no validation error will trigger.